# data sorting effeciency Mysql Order by vs php sorting

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have been loving to use php sorting except using mysql sort order by due to the performance issue. i found this time taking while php sorting is faster than the mysql order by . But is this right approach?

Comment: Where did you find that php sorting is faster than the mysql order by?

Comment: Let's say you have 1 million records and you want to fetch the first 10 ordered by some field. How are you going to do this with PHP only?